# Cached page remains in store even after clearing everything in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser, application-cache

Cached page remains in store even after clearing everything in firefox. I have firefox 7.0.1 and even after i clear cache and then refreshes the page which uses the html5 application cache, the old page is being loaded, which shouldnt be ideally, and this is happening only in ff not in chrome, opera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to clear manually application cache and cache folder from the user directory on the particular os where firefox stores the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl+F5 - this will make a new request for the page instead of using the cached version.

Comment: That's browser cache. With HTML5 application cache, control + F5 has no added meaning. It still serves the page from application cache.